# MVC 4 route prefix and Action url generation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url, action

I have an issue with the URL's generated by @Url.Action in views. I am trying to have multiple controllers with the same name in 1 MVC application (modulair application, each module has a prefix and a Home controller). I am using routes with namespaces to get the routing done and that works fine. The URL's generated by Url.Action in the views have an issue where the prefix is not correct. This is my route definition:

```
//Default added for url building with section, but makes no difference
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{section}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test1",
    url: "Test1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { section = "Test1", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "MVCTest.Controllers.Test1" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Test2",
    url: "Test2/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { section = "Test2", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "MVCTest.Controllers.Test2" }
);
```

This works and the right controllers are resolved when browsing /Test1 and /Test2. Now i have a simple view (Index, used for both actions):

```
Action url: @Url.Action("Action")
```

But the result is always 'Action url: /Test1/Home/Action' Why? I tried without the default route but is has the same result (i added default route for the {section} part of the url).

If i only use the default route and use different controller names (or a custom controller factory which uses the section to determine a namespace) the generation of the action url is correct. Is there anything i can do to fix the Url generation in my route setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it an area you are creating? if so something like the below will work

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { Area = "Test1" }, null)
```

area guide below if  this link is broken a simple google will suffice

http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html

Comment: No i was not creating area's. Maybe area's are a solution... Since all the module data is in a class library (including views) i thought creating a custom solution was a good choice.

Comment: would need to make a custom function for Url.Action() in that case

Comment: I played with area registration in assemblies and it works really well. This way i won't need composition for the modules (each module is an assembly area). Views in assemblies work well with areaviewlocationformats and a custom VirtualPathProvider. Thanks for pointing me in this direction :)